# Java - how to display and edit block of 250 numbers in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-8

I need to be able to display and allow the user to edit an array of 250 int values in a table/grid. It would be best if they were arranged in 25 rows and 10 columns with row and column headings. It should look and work a bit like an excel table. How should I go about this?

[Table of 250 int values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SrUo.png)

Comment: I suggest you get familiar with `TableView`...

Comment: How would you "fold" an array into various columns so the one dimensional int[] is shown in multiple columns instead of 1 column with 250 rows?